# How to publish a html page (generated with Rmarkdown)?

Tags: html, wordpress, web-hosting, r-markdown

I use rmarkdown to create html pages. I would like to know how to publish, simply and efficiently, html pages.

Solutions that I know exist:

- Web hosting: you can purchase a specific domain and host you your files. I have built some wordpress sites with this, but I don't know basics about web security, it is necessary to have a ftp transfer software.
- With google drive, you can host html pages. It is quite simple, you can find the id the the shared document, and enter: googledrive.com/host/DocumentID. But you can not customise the domain name, and this url is redirected to a very complicated name.

It seems that github offers a lot of possilities. I think that some of you have already had the same problem and found the solution. So could you please share ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can host your html easily just check out [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-github-pages-to-host-your-website) or [this](http://jmcglone.com/guides/github-pages/)